# Re-applying to a company after declining a job offer

Tags: interviewing, job-offer

A year ago I applied to a company, went through the entire interview process, and was given an offer. I tentatively accepted the offer, but then turned it down due to the possibility of my wife being relocated to another city.

The same company is still expanding and hiring, and the relocation is not longer an issue and I would like to re-apply.

While it's possible I may be blacklisted, what is the best way to approach the company to apply for one of these positions given my history with them?

Comment: I think the best you can do is be honest about why you declined the offer last time and explain why something like that won't happen this time. Personal experience with this exact thing (wife was suddenly put on bed rest due to pregnancy problems) has resulted in me being "blacklisted" with a company here in town - and that was over 3 years ago.

Comment: Hey Marty, and welcome to [workplace.se]! I think this has the core of a good question, but it is currently attracting close votes. I'm going to make an [edit] to try to get it better answers. If you think I missed the point or messed it up, please feel free to improve it with an [edit] of your own. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the key here is what you told them when you turned the offer down.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reapplying to a job that I was given an offer for but turned down at the time](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/52014/reapplying-to-a-job-that-i-was-given-an-offer-for-but-turned-down-at-the-time)

Answer (score 8):

Reapply and if they ask you explain what happened, most companies will not chew you out over it.

When you applied in the first place, they saw something in you to offer you a job, If they want you and can still see that potential, they will still offer you a job.

My mother who runs her own business has had someone turn down an offer of a job, reapply a few months later as she thought she had a better job offer and has never been happier with her new employee.

As stated above, the way I always see it:

If they want you, they will get you.

Comment: When reapplying, I wouldn't suggest going through the official application process again, but rather reaching out to whomever you spoke to from the company and enquiring that way.

Answer (score 1):

You should be OK if you gave a solid reason when you declined at the end.

In theory a hiring manager would rather hire someone that's there for the long haul instead of taking the job and then leaving 3 months later due to external factors like relocation.  You acknowledged there was an issue and did your best to resolve it.

If your skills are in line with what they are looking for, there shouldn't be an issue.  IF there is an issue, then perhaps it's not the best place for you to wind up.

Answer (score 0):

I think this case is best approached by reaching out to the HR contact or company directly to communicate the situation.  It sounds like they liked you enough for an offer before, and you can explain to them the nature of why you last-minute.passed on it.  You can then express that you found it very interesting, but declined for the personal and unexpected family matter you had.  I find people can understand these situations.  Be friendly about it.

I would be hesitant to just blindly reapply for the position though.  They will likely remember you or have you in the system.  And in all likelihood if it is for the same position then you may not have to go through all the interview steps again if they are still hiring actively.  It is likely you would just need to discuss the situation that happened before and re-assess your interest now.