# Re-applying to a company which offer I initially turned down?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, job-offer

(There's a similar question but my situation is slightly different. So I thought of just asking.)

**Background:** I’m working overseas & my residency is sponsored by the companies that hire me. I am rushing to find a new job because my current company has turned very unstable. They may decide to let me go on a whim and I would be left with little preparation to find a new job / company (that would sponsor my residency).

I have applied on several job postings and the first job interview I’ve attended went well and they decided to hire me and sponsor my work permit. Let’s call this Company A.

However, since the work permit requires approval, I still applied for other jobs, in case my work permit for that Company A gets rejected. I went for another interview and this other company also wants to hire me. Let’s call this Company B. All in all, Company B is more stable (it’s a multi-national company), they have global brands as clients, and based on the interview, I think I would enjoy the work here much better (and more opportunity for growth). Plus, I love the location.

At the back of my mind, once my work permit from the Company A has been approved, I cannot just ask them to cancel it so that I can accept Company B offer instead. It's also unfair. So I have to turn down Company B’s offer if that happens.

**So my question based on the above story:**

Is it okay to re-apply to Company B if I initially turn down their offer (assuming they have the same job opening down the road)? And if I do re-apply, will it be a good thing OR a bad thing that I’ve interviewed with them before? Should I mention that to them when I re-apply?

Comment: Linking to the similar question and explaining why it doesn't fit your situation would be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reapplying to a job that I was given an offer for but turned down at the time](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/52014/reapplying-to-a-job-that-i-was-given-an-offer-for-but-turned-down-at-the-time)

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly re-apply to Company B later. Whether they consider your prior offer and decline as negative is not something you can predict, unless you're aware of specific Company B policies on this matter. The best you can do is be clear that you're turning them down simply because another good offer came in sooner and not because you don't like their offer or company. Logically, the fact that they made you an offer previously is a clear positive sign about you and might help you (but these decisions are not always logical).

However, if you really do believe that Company B will be a better place to work, you should consider backing out of Company A before you start. While this is definitely not a move that will win you any friends at Company A, it happens from time to time when candidates get a better offer. The alternative of accepting A's offer, working there for a very brief period, and *then* switching to B is almost certainly *far worse for A* than simply backing out prior to your start date. Of course you will need to make your own decision about the risks of reputation damage, risks to your permit status, and any unusual contract provisions that may apply.