# Reaching out about a former job offer

Tags: job-search, job-offer

Last year, I had a company reach out to me to discuss a position they were creating and thought I was a good fit. At the time my current employer had just given me a new assignment and out of loyalty or complacency I didn't feel I should leave them at that time.

The VP of the offering company said he understood while I stayed and appreciated my loyalty. He even came back 2 months later and offered the job again with more money but being scared to move, I said no again.  He did say if things ever change to let him know.

After a year, I am regretting not taking that offer last year. I feel like I'm being taken advantage of by my current employer, there is no room for growth and my boss is not open to discussing a pay raise.

However, I don't know how to reach out to the other company. I don't even know if the job is open or not. How could I reach out and let them know to consider me if something should come up?

Comment: How did they contacted you in first place? Surely they had your email or something and you could reply to that or obtain a point of contact there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reapplying to a job that I was given an offer for but turned down at the time](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/52014/reapplying-to-a-job-that-i-was-given-an-offer-for-but-turned-down-at-the-time)

Comment: [Re-applying to a company after declining a job offer.](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/19359)

Answer (score 2):

After almost a year, I'd say that the role has now being filled for some time and you can pretty much consider that offer terminated.

You could try reaching out to the same person and point out that you're ready to explore options again, and see if there's other roles available, but I wouldn't count on it.

Carry on looking for other opportunities in the meantime.

Comment: If they really needed the role filled, its 99.99999% likely its gone.

Comment: @MisterPositive and if they didn't, it's also gone, just for different reason: they may know now that they didn't really needed it in the first place, so they won't pay for it.